# How do I calculate the cost basis of Restricted Stock Units (RSUs)?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, income-tax, rsu

I was granted RSUs that vested 1/3 per year, over 3 years. From E*Trade I have:

- `2016, 133 Shares Vested, 89 Shares Transferred to me, Tax Paid: $3,424.52`
- `2017, 134 Shares Vested, 90 Shares Transferred to me, Tax Paid: $4,795.56`

In 2017 I sold all of these, with proceeds of `$7,814.83` and `$10,709.51` respectively.

Since the original shares were already taxed (I vested 133 and 134, but x-shares were sold for tax purposes, noted above), do I put a cost basis of `$0` on the remaining proceeds I received after selling what was left over?

### **Update**

For completeness, here's my RSU history and how I filed:

```
Vesting #1 | 133 Shares
------------------------
Vest Date:    07/16/2016
PPS at Vest:  $77.83

Shares Assigned:           89
Shares Witheld for Tax:    44
Total Tax Paid (at vest):  $3,424.52
Cost Basis:                $6,926.87

Sale Date:    02/15/2017
PPS at Sale:  $87.95


Vesting #2 | 134 Shares
------------------------
Vest Date:    07/16/2017
PPS at Vest:  $108.99

Shares Assigned:           90
Shares Witheld for Tax:    44
Total Tax Paid (at vest):  $4,795.56
Cost Basis:                $9,809.10

Sale Date:    08/17/2017
PPS at Sale:  $116.47
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For RSUs, the cost basis should be the fair market value (FMV) of the shares on the day they vest. This *should* be listed on your 1099-B from E-Trade, but perhaps not. If it's missing or $0, you'll need to adjust your basis to avoid being double taxed. You should have some kind of records to determine the FMV, for example payslips or you should be able to back-calculate it from your W-2 (because it's included as part of Box 1).

Comment: I've used e-trade for all my RSUs and they never give me a cost basis. Rather then trying to back-calculate from the W-2, I've always just used the share price on the day they vested, which has been close enough.

Comment: @DStanley I'm surprised they're allowed to do that, given the recent cost basis reporting legislation. Share price on the day they vest seems like a reasonable approach.

Comment: I'm double-checking my tax forms, but this along with @DStanley's comment just took me from `($2800)` owed to `$3,000` in refund (we were hovering about $7,000 over the income limit for several tax breaks).

Comment: @MrDuk I would double-check the math - A 5,800 swing in tax seems high after eliminating part of the $18,500 in income, unless you actually had a _loss_ after adding the cost basis and/or are in a high tax bracket.

Comment: I updated my question with a more complete picture of my filing - if someone could maybe take a second peak to verify I'm not completely misunderstanding something?

Comment: @DStanley - My thought (unless I've messed up) is that since I originally had put `$0` for my cost basis, it shot my household income to over `$172,000` and after putting the correct cost basis, that's now dropped to around `$155,000`. While going through deductions/credits, I saw several that I didn't qualify for because the cutoff was `$165,000` - maybe this kicked some of those back in?

Comment: @MrDuk Very possible. That could explain the large jump. Congratulations! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can find your adjusted cost basis on a supplemental form provided by E*TRADE SECURITIES LLC. This form is separate from a 1099-B.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Finally I figured out how to deal with RSU stocks with Turbo Tax Perimer version. My forms are all from Etrade.
Information you need are: 1) 1099 form from Etrade 2) Stock Plan Transactions Supplement 3) Employee Stock Plan Release Confirmation. Etrade only send us the 1099. You can go their website find 2nd and 3rd form yourself, or call them to help you.

Once you have those forms (you can import 1099 from Etrade, and only 1099 will be imported). Follow TusboTax step by step.  At some point, TurboTax will ask you what stock you have, you need to choose the option has RSU. At some point, it will allow you to edit each sale of you stocks, you need to click on edit, and follow instructions to enter information from 2nd and 3rd forms.